# Cannot create MS MDT Database on SQL 2012 Express

Tags: sql, mdt-2012

I am trying to create a new SQL Server 2012 Express database via MDT 2013. When I did that I got the error above. I have completely rebuilt the server yet this error persists. Now when right-click on theDatabase node in MDT I get action progress dialog but it never finishes.

I used the latest ADK to install the deployment tools and SQL.

Below is the error from the Event Log:

```
Application: mmc.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Executive.MmcThreadMessageWindow.OnThreadException(Exception e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Internal.SnapInMessagePumpProxy.Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Internal.ISnapInMessagePumpProxy.Run()
   at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Executive.SnapInThread.OnThreadStart()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Can anyone help? I am at a complete loss at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was something in the settings.xml

I deleted and recreated it the I could add the DB.

The file looked OK.